# Cannot find a parameter with this name: indication

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation, floating-action-button

Hello i'm trying to draw a Canvas in compose.. but when I use the indication parameter in Modifier.clickable() I get this  error  `Cannot find a parameter with this name: indication`

code:

```
@Composable
fun MiniFloatingActionButton(item: MultiFabItem, onFabItemClicked: (item: MultiFabItem) -> Unit) {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp)
            .clickable(
                onClick = { onFabItemClicked(item) },
                //Cannot find a parameter with this name: indication
                indication = rememberRipple(
                    bounded = false,
                    radius = 20.dp,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSecondary
                )
            )
    ) {
//        …
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the [**`interactionSource`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).clickable(androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.foundation.Indication,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role,kotlin.Function0)) parameter

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

Canvas(
    modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp)
        .clickable(
            onClick = {  },
            indication = rememberRipple(
                bounded = false,
                radius = 20.dp,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSecondary
            ),
            interactionSource = interactionSource
        )
) {
    //…
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `interactionSource` as well in the `clickable`.

If you don't have any `interactionSource`, use

```
interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
```